# golang: how to handle blocking tasks optimally?

Tags: go

As known, the goroutine is synchronous but non-blocking processing unit.
The golang scheduler handles the non-blocking task, e.g. socket, timer, signal or other events from char devices very well.

But how about **block device io or CPU sensitive task**? They couldn't be interrupted until finish, and not multiplexed. The OS thread which runs the goroutine would freeze until the goroutine returns or yields. In that case, the scheduling granularity becomes bad.

Of course, you could split the tasks into smaller sub-tasks in your codes, for example, do not copy 1GB file at one time, instead, copy first 10MB, yield, and copy another 10MB, etc, so that the other goroutines within the same OS thread get chance to run. Another example for CPU-bound task: zip a file part by part and merge them finally.

But that breaks the convenience of sequential programming, and the manual scheduling is hard to estimate evenly, compared to the OS scheduling upon the OS threads.

The nginx has similar issue, it's multi-worker-processes program, one process for one CPU core, similar to the best practice of the GOMAXPROCS. It brings in the thread pool to handle the blocking tasks. Maybe it's good for golang too.
I am curious why golang has no OS threading API, which should be good supplement to goroutine for blocking tasks.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how the golang scheduler works (and are confused about blocking and non-blocking calls). [This article](https://morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler) is a bit old (especially since go1.5), but it explain the basics of the scheduler quite clearly.

Comment: Go does let you control the threads a bit through the [`runtime`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/) package

Comment: @Elwinar, you misunderstand my point. Note that I refer to block device io and cpu sensitive task. The user-space scheduling relies on the fact that the tasks are non-blocking, e.g. socket and multiplexing via OS specific mechanism, e.g. epoll. That is, the schedule switch between goroutines only happens at the EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK syscall return or goroutine explicit yield. But it could not break the blocking syscall. However, the OS kernel could do it, for example, when you copy 1GB file, the linux kernel would invoke cond_resched() at each PAGE-size write iteration to give up the CPU.

Comment: From what I know, routines that do filesystem operation are handled by the scheduler and waked when their operation is ready, much like routines that do network operations.

Comment: @Elwinar, when the syscall enters, e.g. write() 1GB buffer into file, you have no way to break it until it returns, and that's what I means "blocking". For example, the write() consumes 60s to complete, and during that 60s period, the OS thread chosen by golang (one of the threads specified by GOMAXPROCS) could not do scheduling. However, in socket case, if you write() 1GB buffer to the peer, if the buffer is not enough, or the peer is slow receiving, or the network is in congestion, the write() would returns with EWOULDBLOCK error, then the scheduler would run next ready goroutine.

Comment: Whitout being an expert on the matter, I think the same process is (somewhat) happening with the block devices. That's why there is so many caches between CPU and HDD, and why doing benchmarks that involve writing to files is a hassle.

Comment: @Elwinar, besides the hardware caches, the linux page cache layer also boost the block deivce io, but I'm worrying about the high-load cases, where the caches could not help. And don't forget the CPU-bound tasks, e.g. file compression, ssl handshake, etc. For those pure CPU consuming tasks, the OS threading is the only way to enable scheduling among the tasks, because only the OS kernel could interleave the time slots between the tasks.

Comment: For this kind of tasks, there is a [runtime.Gosched()](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Gosched) function that seems to be used to yield manually to the scheduler.

Comment: Additionnally, starting from go1.2, there is a [random pre-emption](http://golang.org/doc/go1.2#preemption) on function call. That is, each call to a function may yield to the scheduler.

Comment: why you say goroutine is  `synchronous`? multiple goroutines may be running at sametime.

Comment: @Elwinar, Gosched() is what I means "yield", of course I know that function. See my post content, I said manual scheduling by splitting the task could help, but I also doubt it's not convenient and precise. And the random preemption is related to looping only, but I concern about time-consuming and not-interrupted syscall invocation.

Comment: good discusses about this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/Luje-okL4jI

Comment: @JiangYD, "synchronous" means the opposite to asynchronous callback way, like nodejs. Of course I know goroutine is concurrent and even parallel in multiple CPU-core machines.

Comment: From what I know, there is no way to "split" a syscall. You could try to use the [runtime.LockOSThread](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread) function so the routine is alone on its thread and the OS scheduler can do its job.

Comment: @kingluo `asynchronous callback way` is saying a way to get function return value, but goroutine can not return a value in function level. so I think we can not say goroutine is synchronous.

Comment: @Elwinar, so that's why I mention OS threading, only the OS kernel could split the syscall or long CPU consumption in proper unit and do it in good timing. The runtime.LockOSThread() has noting to do with here. It only bind the goroutine to current thread, but what I mention is when your goroutine enters the syscall, e.g. write(), how to avoid long occupation of the thread which is supposed to switch other ready goroutine to run, especially when the GOMAXPROCS configured to the exact number of the CPU. Of course, increase GOMAXPROCS is an alternative solution.

Comment: @JiangYD, so you think the goroutine is asynchronous? ok, whatever, as long as it could clarify the facts the goroutine is sequential processing unit and concurrent to each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go has specifically chosen to not directly expose OS threads to the user, and instead chose an M:N threading model. Your unit of execution in Go is the goroutine, which will be multiplexed on N number of OS threads.

In the *rare* case you have a CPU intensive calculation that contains no preemption points and insufficient OS threads to continue running other goroutines, you have 2 choices; increase GOMAXPROCS, or insert `runtime.Gosched()` calls to yield to other goroutines.

In the case of blocking syscalls, the Go scheduler will automatically dispatch a new OS thread (the time limit to consider a syscall "blocking" has been 20us), and since non-network IO is a series of blocking syscalls, it will almost always be assigned to a dedicated OS thread. Since Go already uses an M:N threading model, the user is usually unaware of the underlying scheduler choices, and can write the program the same as if the runtime used asynchronous IO.

There is an [open issue](https://golang.org/issue/6817) to consider using asynchronous file IO, but there are many issues to overcome, like shortcomings in the Linux aio api, cross-platform compatibility, and interactions with all the various filesystems and devices with which you can do IO.

Comment: Thanks. The document said "There is no limit to the number of threads that can be blocked in system calls on behalf of Go code" (and I also check the source codes roughly), so it's possible that if there is many long running blocking syscalls, then the number of blocking threads would grow until it exceeds the system limit and crashes?

Comment: @kingluo: theoretically yes, but if you're trying to e.g. read from millions of files simultaneously, you're probably doing something wrong (not to mention you would likely hit other limits in the meantime).  The exception is for calls to the native host resolver, where there a limit places for in-flight requests to limit the number of threads that could be used.